# How to automatically concatenate strings in javascript

Tags: sublimetext2

I'd really like to have some automatic string concatenation when I line break in the middle of a string on javascript. I commonly have to break when I reach 80 chars and would like an easy way of doing this.

For example:

```
var string = '<html>Here is some html in a string so it is going to be very long</html>';
```

I'd like to just line break in the middle of that and Sublime text to automatically concatenate into

```
var string = '<html>Here is some html in a string so it is going' +  
    'to be very long</html>';
```

Is this possible? Is there a plugin?

Comment: did you check search engines and the sublime package manager to find out? can you tell us whether it exists on the internet as far as you can find, so we can tell whether we need to tell you to search, or help you?

Comment: most IDE's have **line wrap** mode..

Comment: Why do you have to break at 80 char? I could understand on nano or console text editor since the additional characters go out of screen, but not on sublimetext, search for wrap mode.

Comment: yes I checked search engines and plugins. line wrap is very different, I dont want to visually wrap, I want to actually stop my code going over 80 characters. It's a commonly used coding convention and part of my team's linter. WebStorm has a feature like this which is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a macro, below is an example I made earlier.

You can change the `width` argument to the `wrap_lines` command if you want to break at something other than 80 characters. You can also substitute a different `characters` sequence e.g. if you're editing Python and you want to insert triple quotes instead.

Save the script below as a Sublime JSON macro file e.g. `split-literal.sublime-macro`. In Sublime goto "Preferences->Browse Packages" and then copy the macro file into Packages/User. The macro should now appear in the Tools->Macros menu.

To assign a hotkey to this macro, goto "Preferences->Key Bindings - User" and add the following to the keymap file:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+w"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file":"Packages/User/split-literal.sublime-macro"} }
]
```

Obviously substitute whatever hotkey you prefer in place of `ctrl+shift+w`.

Example JSON macro in full:

```
[
    {
        "args":
        {
            "width": 80
        },
        "command": "wrap_lines"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "by": "lines",
            "forward": false
        },
        "command": "move"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "to": "eol"
        },
        "command": "move_to"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "characters": "' +"
        },
        "command": "insert"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "by": "lines",
            "forward": true
        },
        "command": "move"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "to": "bol"
        },
        "command": "move_to"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "characters": "    '"
        },
        "command": "insert"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "to": "eol"
        },
        "command": "move_to"
    }
]
```

Comment: I like where you're going with this but it's not quite good enough.  You have to invoke it manually and it's not smart about the context - e.g. if there's a line of code with some string literals in it but the wrap point isn't in the string literal then it does the wrong thing.  What I should really like is for Sublime to just recognize that when I hit ```<enter>``` and the cursor is within a string literal, it needs to do ```' +<enter>'``` - basically the same thing pretty much any IDE will do.

Answer (score 1):

See the plugin script in this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/469240/29809) which breaks or inserts newlines at the wrap point.

This script obviously needs to check if its operating on strings or not but as a quick thing I tried re-purposing the script to add quotes by changing this line:

`v.insert(e, textpos, "'+\n'{0}".format(next_line_indent_string))`

but that seems to cause ST2 to hang/crash. If you remove the `+` character, it inserts quotes, newline quotes fine. I'm afraid this is where my python skills run out.

I'm hoping this would point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

To do this I use Sublime-Wrap-Plus package for Sublime Text 2 or 3. It's the best package I've found so far to do lines wrapping so far. You can find it on GitHub (https://github.com/ehuss/Sublime-Wrap-Plus) and install it using Package Control. It will do *most* of the job for **text lines**, but unfortunately for now it doesn't handle string in code like in your example.